# Session is passing like a primitive type?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have a MVC Core Dotnet application and basically I wanted to load a view of session data but also remove the session after the page loads.  My code works but I don't understand why

```
public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken, int totalPrice){
    //some stripe code that went here...

    var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetCart();
    ClearSession();
    return View(cart);
}

protected void ClearSession(){
    //creates a new instance if cart doesnt exist otherwise returns it
    var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetCart();

    //clears the items from the collection using .Clear() ...
    cart.RemoveAll();
    HttpContext.Session.SetCart(cart);
}
```

the code works when its placed in a new method like so.. but if I placed it in the same method it doesn't work.  I am surprised by placing it in a new method it worked as it goes against my understand of how pass by value works with object types.. (the location of the object will be passed).  Its acting like a copy of the object was made when I cleared the Item list in the new method.

Why does this code work?

Comment: When you do `var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetCart();` in `Charge` method, it creates a local copy of whatever is the in the session and is gets passed to the view. In method `ClearSession` another local copy is created and modified and saved back to the session. That's how it works.

Comment: To get your desired behavior, you need to create an empty collection and save is to session after you do `var cart = HttpContext.Session.GetCart();` to clear the session.